# Adding a class to current menu tab

Tags: jquery, css, menu, tabs

I'm using the following to toggle between 3 different divs..

Check out the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjS3E/).

I've come unstuck trying to find a method to apply a different background color to the currently selected menu tab, (including the default tab that the page loads with - "Weekly")

It's not possible to add a class to a class is it?

Any ideas how I could do this with jQuery?

Here's my code...

jQuery :

```
 jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
    newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);
    console.log(index+newTarget)
    jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').fadeIn('fast')
    return false;
})
```

CSS :

```
 .viewSchedule {}
 .viewBTN {display:block;width:auto;height:auto;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;background:#ccc;color:#242424;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;float:left;margin-left:10px;font-family:dina,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;text-align:center;}
 .viewBTN:hover {background:#FFF;color:#333;}


 .targetSched {display: none}
 .targetSched.first {display: block}
```

HTML :

```
 <a class="viewSchedule" target="1"><span class="viewBTN">WEEKLY</span></a>
 <a class="viewSchedule" target="2"><span class="viewBTN">DAILY</span></a>
 <a class="viewSchedule" target="3"><span class="viewBTN">LIST</span></a>

 <br /><br /><br /><br />

 <div id="sh-week" class="targetSched first">WEEKLY CONTENT</div>
 <div id="sh-daily" class="targetSched">DAILY CONTENT</div>
 <div id="sh-list" class="targetSched">LIST CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can add multiple class to a single element .

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/dUFwC/1/)**

JAvascript

```
jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
        newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);

    $(".viewSchedule.active").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
    console.log(index+newTarget)
        jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')
        newTarget.delay('fast').fadeIn('fast')
        return false;
    })
```

CSS

```
.viewSchedule {}
.viewBTN {display:block;width:auto;height:auto;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;background:#ccc;color:#242424;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;float:left;margin-left:10px;font-family:dina,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;text-align:center;}
.viewBTN:hover {background:#FFF;color:#333;}


.viewSchedule.active .viewBTN{
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
.targetSched {display: none}
.targetSched.first {display: block}
```

Comment: This will not be correct. `$(this).addClass("active");` will add a class to the link, not the button. See my answer.

Comment: the goal is to highlight active button

Comment: Exactly, and to override the button style you need to set add the class to the `.viewBTN` span.

Comment: Oh, alright. My mistake. Well, the asker can choose whichever answer that suits him best. Have a nice day.

Comment: we both are right, programming has many ways to do same thing

Comment: Thanks this is great but only solves half of my problem. I need the tab that is active on page load to have the class added too? Can I just add this manually and the JS will remove it when another tab is clicked?

Comment: Just tried it in a fiddle and to answer my own question - Yes. I can just add the selected class in the markup. Thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kristofferj/zjS3E/3/)

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.viewSchedule').click(function () {
    $('.viewBTN').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).find('.viewBTN').addClass('selected');

    var index = $(this).index(),
    newTarget = jQuery('.targetSched').eq(index);
    jQuery('.targetSched').not(newTarget).fadeOut('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').fadeIn('fast')        
    return false;
})
```

CSS:

```
.selected {background: blue}
```

Comment: this is not about who is wrong or right, its just about what is solution.  +1 for your try, thanks